# Type error for http outgoing value.replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, replace

I'm having this random node error after deleting something in my database and exploring a route. What is this caused by?

```
_http_outgoing.js:299
    value = value.replace(/[\r\n]+[ \t]*/g, '');
                  ^
TypeError: value.replace is not a function
    at storeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:299:19)
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage._storeHeader (_http_outgoing.js:215:9)
    at ClientRequest._implicitHeader (_http_client.js:166:8)
    at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:539:10)
    at Request.end (/Users/thomas/Desktop/node-project-app/node-project-api/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/request.js:1363:12)
    at end (/Users/thomas/Desktop/node-project-app/node-project-api/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/request.js:563:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/thomas/Desktop/node-project-app/node-project-api/node_modules/request-promise/node_modules/request/request.js:577:7)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
15 Jul 11:26:54 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: where's your code?  It's really hard to tell what's going wrong without seeing what's happening.

Comment: No idea what `_http_outgoing.js` is, but my guess would be that something is setting `value` to be a number instead of a string.

Comment: Sorry I don't have any specific code causing this, I had to track it down, believe I solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this error is caused when you set a [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) (in my case [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise)) parameter (in my case header) to a function instead of a string.